# Showing that $\Bbb{N}$ is well-ordered. Do I need an arbitrary case?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

proof (The way I did it):

Base Case: Consider $\{1,2\}$.  Clearly $1<2$ by the natural order in $\Bbb{N}$.

Inductive case: Suppose $\{1,2,...,n\}$ is well-ordered then since $n<n+1$, the set $\{1,2,...,n,n+1\}$ is also well-ordered due to transitivity in $\Bbb{N}$.

My professor told me that I **need** to use an arbitrary well-ordered subset of $\Bbb{N}$ in my inductive case. But, I do not think that we **need** to because any arbitrary case will be "eventually" be covered by the method of induction I used above, for some $m+1\in\Bbb{N}$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your proof has other issues too. You should show that **any non-empty subset S** of $\mathbb{N}$ has a minimum element. You haven't proven that.

Comment: That's exactly the point I was driving at.. I am arguing that that $S$ will eventually be covered by some $m+1\in\Bbb{N}$. More specifically, $S\subseteq \{1,2,...,m+1\}$. That's why I am thinking that I do not need to do it that way.

Comment: Your argument, in its current form, proves that any subset of the form $\{1,2,\cdots,k\}$ is well-ordered. It says nothing about sets of infinite cardinality in $\mathbb{N}$ to be honest. Your argument, improved a little bit, can prove that any subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with finite cardinality is well-ordered. However, it can't prove why, let's say even numbers, are well-ordered. Do you see the problem? You cannot cover even numbers as a finite union of sets that you have proved to be well-ordered.

Comment: I don't understand why even having proving it by induction, it still doesn't cover infinite cardinality.

Comment: You're misinterpreting your inductive proof. What you have proved is that any set of the form $\{1,2,\cdots,\k\}$ is well-ordered. If we slightly improve your argument, one can prove that any subset of natural numbers with finite cardinality is well-ordered. The induction will of course be done on the size of the subset under consideration. However, the induction will not prove anything about subsets of infinite cardinality because "infinity" is no a natural number. So, subsets of infinite cardinality will not be covered by your induction. Does that make sense?

Comment: So in the inductive case, one cannot use an arbitrary finite subset of $k$ elements of $\Bbb{N}$?

Comment: You can use an arbitrary finite subset of $k$ elements in $\mathbb{N}$, but you cannot proceed from proving that finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are well-ordered to proving that "general subsets" of $\mathbb{N}$ (with infinite cardinality) are well-ordered.

Comment: @TheLastCipher What definition of well-ordered are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what you have to show to prove that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered.

> Definition: A set $A$ is called well-ordered if there exists a total
>   ordering $\leq_*$ on $A$ such that **any** subset $B \subseteq A$ has
>   a minimum element with respect to $\leq_*$.

Now what does mathematical induction says?

It says that suppose I have a set of statements $P(n)$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and I know that $P(1)$ is true. If $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ then $P(n)$ is true for any natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

So, what you have proved is that any finite set of the form $\{1,2,\cdots,k\}$ is well-ordered. Of course, there are many subsets in $\mathbb{N}$ that are not necessarily of this form. But let's ignore this issue for now because it can be fixed easily.

Let's say that we have proved $P(k)=\{ \text{a set of size k is well-ordered}\}$ is true by mathematical induction using your method. Can we conclude that a set of infinite cardinality is well-ordered? No! Because infinity is not a natural number. So, you still need to prove that sets of infinite cardinality in $\mathbb{N}$ are well-ordered to have demonstrated that "**any subset** of $\mathbb{N}$" has a minimum element.

**Here's a proof:**

**Claim I:** Any non-empty subset of natural numbers with finite cardinality is well-ordered.

**Proof:** we will use mathematical induction on the size of subsets $\emptyset \neq A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ where $|A| < \infty$.

If $n=1$, then we have only one element in the set and it is trivial. If $|A|=n+1$, consider $B \subset A$ which is obtained by removing only one element from $A$, i.e. $B \cup \{a\}=A$. Since $|B|=n$, it has a minimum element $b_0$. Now choose $a_0 = \min\{a,b_0\}$. Q.E.D

**Claim II:** Any non-empty subset of natural numbers, even with infinite cardinality is well-ordered.

**Proof:** the idea of the proof for this part was first posted by William Elliot. Take $\emptyset \neq A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. Since $A$ is non-empty, there exists some natural number $m \in A$. Consider $B=\{n \in A: n \leq m\}$. $B$ has at most $m$ elements and therefore is finite and has a minimum: $b_0$.
Now notice that $A = B \cup B^c$ where $B^c$ is the complement of $B$, i.e. $B^c = \{ n \in A: n > m \}$.

Now, $b_0$ is also the minimum of $A$ because any element $a$ in $A$ is either in $B$ or $B^c$. If $a$ is in $B$, then $b_0 \leq a$. If $a$ is in $B^c$, then $a > m$ and $b_0 \leq m$ and again we see that $b_0 \leq a$. Q.E.D.

Comment: How does using an arbitrary set of $k$ elements in the inductive case help prove the case for infinite cardinality subsets of $\Bbb{N}$?

Comment: @TheLastCipher I never claimed that it helps you prove the case for infinite cardinality. Did I? The part where you have to move from finite subsets of natural numbers to more general subsets is the difficult part.

Comment: You never claimed that. But my professor did as to my confusion.

Comment: @TheLastCipher  I don't know the argument your professor had in mind. Maybe your professor had an argument like William Elliot's or maybe not. I don't know. I'm not your professor xD

Comment: I would have to check with my classmate's notes to be sure. But if I remember correctly, it was nothing like William Elliot's argument x(

Comment: @TheLastCipher  I put the pieces of puzzle together and I think the proof is now complete.

Comment: In the last sentence, what is "it's" referring to? I don't think the minimum of $B$ can be in $B^c$ because everything in $B^c$ is greater than $B$..? By the way, thank you for the time you're putting in!! Thank you.

Comment: @TheLastCipher  I rephrased the last paragraph to make it clearer. Does it make sense now? The minimum of $B$ was not in $B^c$. $a \in A$ which is an arbitrary element of $A$ was assumed to be in $B^c$.

Comment: Yes, I understood the first time, but was afraid I was missing something so I had to clarify. Thank you for putting a lot of time in this!

Comment: @TheLastCipher  I'm glad it was helpful and you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure how you're showing well-orderedness. A total order is a well-ordering if every non-empty subset of the set has a minimum element. You haven't really established this. For example, how would your argument establish that $\lbrace 2, 3\rbrace$ has a minimum? It doesn't fit with any of the sets $\lbrace 1, 2, \ldots, n \rbrace$, and it's not clear how it inherits structure from supersets like $\lbrace 1, 2, 3 \rbrace$ from your argument alone.

Then there's the problem that you're missing out on infinite sets. Let's say that you have established that the set $\lbrace 1, \ldots, n \rbrace$ is well-ordered for all $n$. How does this prove that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered? You haven't accounted for any infinite sets. For example, the set $\mathbb{N}$ itself is not a subset of $\lbrace 1, \ldots, n \rbrace$ for any $n$, so why must it have a minimum?

No, even if you nest countably many well-ordered sets, this does not produce a well-ordered set necessarily. For example, the sets
$$\lbrace -n, -n + 1, \ldots, n - 1, n \rbrace$$
are well-ordered and will union to give $\mathbb{Z}$, which is not well-ordered.

So, in short, **yes** you need an arbitrary case.

Comment: $\{2,3\}$ inherits structure in $\{1,2,3\}$ due to transitivity of order...?

Comment: I don't really follow. It's not difficult to conclude this, but if I were marking this, this line of the proof would not convince me that you necessarily understood the reasoning behind it. Maybe you just need to elaborate on this point? But even then, there are bigger issues with the proof.

Answer (score 1):

First show that every finite subset of $\Bbb{N}$ has a minimum.
This OP has done.

Assume $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is not empty.  Pick any $n$ in $A$.
Show $B = \{ k \in A: k \leq n \}$ is a finite set.
Thus $B$ has a minimum $m$.  Show $m$ is a minimum in $A$.

Comment: Should $A$ be a proper subset of $\Bbb{N}$?

Comment: This 'answer' is useless.  There is already a full answer, your sniping would be a better match for Yahoo Answers.